# C# Multithreading with unmanaged DLL imported

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have got the follwing problem and question.

Fist of all I have to use .NET 3.5. I'm working out an DLL that is used in an multithreading host application.

My new DLL loads an DLL by using the DllImport function. This imported DLL is really old and do not provide multithreading, so my knowledge. It provides functions to open an USB Hardware port an functions to trigger a DATA read.

I got rare support from the company producing this hardware and an NON-multithreading C# demo software, that is working fine.

I started to prot this appliction into my DLL, and it works sometimes. After debuging I'm actualy at the point, that it is a multithreading issues, the host appication is not only multitreading also multi service.

I started to implement multithreading in the demo application. And found out, that I'm not familiar with that. 
I use the lock object to ensure hardware communiction is not in parallel. but the threads locked eachother, also without the external DLL.

First of all the Mainthread is now one of my threads an a new created thread is started from this, that it is prefoming hardware scan results colletion to simulate unknown hardware communiction in my host appliction my dll is running in.

after a while, not reproducable the application freezes an waits to get the lock, this happens in the MainThread.
Is it possible to use lock in MainThread at all? Or should the MainThread be untouched, running all the time?

Sorry that I cannot provide the code, but I hope somebody understands an can give an hint to solve the problem.

If I have to use maybe 4.5 .net Version, I need some Informations to load the external DLL, I tried it and got problems with the DllImport function.

Thanks for reading and thinking about it.

Comment: If the USB device does not support concurrent operations, then, you need to manage how your application access it.  You have currently implemented a locking mechanism but it's failing.  Without the code, it is difficult to determine why.  Consider creating a wrapper class with the singleton pattern that manages access to the USB device.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share your code as well as your description of the problem. It's difficult to troubleshoot problems by reading a synopsis. Please also be sure to highlight where errors occur.